# Need to share files with different users ?What is FILE-id here?use JavaScript

Tags: google-drive-api

```
<html>
  <head>


    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">\
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        init = function() {
        s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient('<YOUR_APP_ID>');
```

//What is the way to get the file-id in JS.I want to share the files with different users
            s.setItemIds([""]);
        }

```
    window.onload = function() {

        gapi.load('drive-share', init);

    }


    </script>

  </head>

  <body>


      <button onclick="s.showSettingsDialog()">Share</button>
```

//How is showSettingDialog() working

```
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first use [Files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).
There are quickstart codes for various languages on this page you might want to try.

Then, you will see list of [File Resources](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource).
Attribute "id" in File Resources is the file id you want.

Or, if you are working on a specific Google Docs files, you can see file id in the URL.